# Calculate group by Machines percentages in TSQL

Tags: t-sql

I want to calculate the percentages and counts from the sample dataset below.
I have included the screenshot that contains the expected output.

```html
Sample Data 
Machine Environment   Status
GA      PROD            Compliance
GA      PROD            Non Compliance
NY      NonProd       Compliance
NY      NonProd       Non Compliance
CA      PROD            Non Compliance
CA      PROD            Compliance
CA      PROD            Non Compliance
CA      NonProd       Compliance
WA      PROD            Non Compliance
WA      NonProd       Compliance
DN      PROD            Compliance
DN      PROD            Non Compliance

Expected output

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Formula:            
Prodcompliance%     Prod-Compliance/ProdTotal   
NonProdCompliance%  NonProd-Compliance/NonProdTotal
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you don't even know where to start, you might look at the technique of summing the result of an expression, using `sum(iif(...`

Comment: Search around for `PIVOT`

Comment: Will work with PIVOT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used two pivots to get the desired ourput for prod and nonprod then combine with union to get the grand totals.  I think your expected output "WA' is having wrong values as it differs with my data.

```
--Sample Data  

 CREATE TABLE Machine
 (
 Machine varchar(10)
 ,Environment varchar(10)
 , [Status]  Varchar(100))


    insert into  Machine VALUES  (  'GA',      'PROD',            'Compliance' )
    ,('GA',     'PROD',            'Non Compliance')
    ,('NY',      'NonProd',       'Compliance')
    ,('NY',      'NonProd',       'Non Compliance')
    ,('CA',      'PROD',            'Non Compliance')
    ,('CA',     'PROD',            'Compliance')
    ,('CA',     'PROD',            'Non Compliance')
    ,('CA',      'NonProd',     'Compliance')
    ,('WA',      'PROD',            'Non Compliance')
    ,('WA',      'NonProd',       'Compliance')
    ,('DN',      'PROD',            'Compliance')
    ,('DN',      'PROD',            'Non Compliance')
 --Query

  SELECT  
   AB.Machine 
   , ISNULL(A.Prod_total , 0)AS [Prod_total]
   , ISNULL(A.Compliance, 0) AS  [Prod_Compliance]
   , ISNULL(A.[Non Compliance], 0) AS  [Prod_Non Compliance]
   , ISNULL(A.[Percentage_compliance], 0 ) AS [Prod_Percentage_Compliance]
   , ISNULL(B.Prod_total , 0)AS [Non Prod_total]
   , ISNULL(B.Compliance, 0) AS  [Non Prod_Compliance]
   , ISNULL(B.[Non Compliance], 0) AS  [Non Prod_Non Compliance]
   , ISNULL(B.[Percentage_compliance], 0 ) AS [Non Prod_Percentage_Compliance]
INTO #Temp_MachineData
FROM 
(
   SELECT Distinct Machine  FROM Machine   ) AS AB LEFT JOIN 
 (
    SELECT 
      Machine
      ,[Total] as [Prod_total]
      ,[Compliance]
      ,[Non Compliance]
      , CAST(( [Compliance] /CAST([Total]AS decimal (10,2)) )  * 100 AS     DECIMAL(10,2) ) AS [Percentage_compliance]
   FROM
     (
      SELECT 
        DISTINCT Machine
         , Environment
         ,[Status]
         ,COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY  Machine, [Status] ORDER BY  Machine) AS [Count_]
        ,COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION  By Machine ORDER BY  Machine ) AS  [Total]
      FROM Machine
      WHERE Environment = 'PROD' 
     ) AS [src]
      PIVOT 
      (
         MAX([Count_]) FOR [Status] In  ([Compliance], [Non Compliance]) ) AS pivoted1

        ) AS A ON AB.Machine = A.Machine

      LEFT JOIN

 (
    SELECT 
      Machine
      ,[Total] AS [Prod_total]
      ,[Compliance]
      ,[Non Compliance]
       , CAST(( [Compliance] /CAST([Total]AS decimal (10,2)) )  * 100 AS DECIMAL(10,2) ) AS [Percentage_compliance]
     FROM
     (
       SELECT DISTINCT Machine, Environment,[Status]
        ,COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY  Machine, [Status] ORDER BY  Machine) AS [COunt_]
        ,COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION  By Machine ORDER BY  Machine ) AS  [Total]
        FROM Machine
       WHERE Environment = 'NonProd'
      ) AS [src]
   PIVOT 
     (
      MAX([Count_]) FOR [Status] In  ([Compliance], [Non Compliance]) ) AS pivoted1

      ) AS B ON AB.Machine  = B.Machine

SELECT 

  A.*
    , A.[Prod_total] + A.[Non Prod_total]  AS  [ToatlProdNonProd]
  FROM
   (
    SELECT * 
     FROM  #Temp_MachineData

    UNION ALL 

   SELECT 
    'Total' AS  [Machine]
    , SUM([Prod_total]) AS  [Prod_total]
    , SUM ([Prod_Compliance] ) AS [Prod_Compliance]
    , SUM ([Prod_Non Compliance] ) AS  [Prod_Non Compliance]
    , SUM ([Prod_Percentage_Compliance]) AS [Prod_Percentage_Compliance]
    , SUM ([Non Prod_total] ) AS [Non Prod_total]
    , SUM ([Non Prod_Compliance] ) AS  [Non Prod_Compliance]
    , SUM ([Non Prod_Non Compliance] ) AS [Non Prod_Non Compliance]
    , SUM ([Non Prod_Percentage_Compliance]) AS [Non Prod_Percentage_Compliance]
   FROM     #Temp_MachineData
    ) AS A

   DROP TABLE #Temp_MachineData
```

[image: Result]

Comment: @Kusu Let me know if this answer helps or if you need any alterations to the answer. Happy to help. By the way this is  complete solution. Other formatting I hope you can handle. Let me know. Thanks :)